# Make overlay button with transparent background color

Tags: kotlin, button, overlay

I try to create overlay button with transparent background, but it's not fully transparent.
I set a transparent background color and transparent theme, but still I can observe background of this button. Ideally, it should be oval overlay button without additional background.
[image]

```
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private fun createButton(){
        overlayButton = ImageButton(this)
        overlayButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparentColor)
        overlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ready_button)
        overlayButton.setOnTouchListener(this)
        overlayButton.setOnClickListener(this)

        val layoutFlag = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Old-fashioned model", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION
        }
        params = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
        params.type = layoutFlag
        params.width = (mWidth*0.2).roundToInt()
        params.height = (mWidth*0.2).roundToInt()
        params.x = mWidth
        params.y = (mHeight*0.15).roundToInt()
        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT


        wmgr.addView(overlayButton,params)
    }
```

ready_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:background="#0000000">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@color/readyColor1"
    android:endColor="@color/readyColor2" />

<corners android:radius="1000dp" />
</shape>
```

in colors I have this color:

```
<color name="transparentColor" >#00000000</color>
```

Used style in this service window:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparentColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```